# IBeacon Locate app supports Nexus 5 and Nexus 4?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does RadiusNetwork's IBeacon Locate app supports Nexus 5 and Nexus 4 ?
Both of my devices are running stock android 4.4.2.
I am trying to detect an iBeacon, which is detectable from an iPhone.

I got "Unfortunately, Bluetooth Share has stopped." every time i'm running the App.
For Nexus 4, i turned off the Wifi before running the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048721/bluetooth-share-has-stopped-working which is a more current question related to this same bug in the android bluetooth system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris Stratton suggested in his comment, this is a bug in Android bluetooth code.
In Chris' link, davidgyoung also provided a link to [his blog](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/04/02/a-solution-for-android-bluetooth-crashes.html) about solution to this issue.

Thanks to both!