# "Bluetooth share has stopped working" when performing LeScan

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a bunch of various Android phones in front of me all running 4.3/4.4 and they all seem to be suffering from some bug in Bluetooth.  The app I am running is simply scanning for other bluetooth devices around it using this callback: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html

Just LogCatting the data and still having problems...

Does anyone know about this bug and have a fix for it?  I really need to get bluetooth scanning stable for a deadline I have tomorrow for a demo of my application...

Thanks.

EDIT: Supposedly in 4.4.3 (or 4.4.4) this was resolved. (Of course the day of our presentation for the project...did us no good).  The main issue was the XML file keeping track of mac addresses growing over the size of 2000 and then crashing...a system reset would clear the xml file, thus solving the problem temporarily.

Comment: Yes, there is an unhandled case in the internal logic of the Android platform code where it assumes it will always be able to allocate a remote device record and if it cannot it crashes completely. Try toggling airplane mode briefly as this may clear the devices records (though power cycling does not).  Otherwise, a factory reset definitely will.

Comment: Is there anyway to tap down into the Qualcomm drivers directly and write our own implementation since the Android platform code is bad?  Has someone possibly already done this?

Comment: No, unless you are able to install your own AOSP based build on the device (though if you had root you might be able to crudely wipe out the records).  Did the airplane mode toggle temporarily clear it for you?

Comment: No the airplane mode toggle did not work.  Was looking to install Cyanongenmod and see if that worked...I read somewhere on their forums a few days ago they had a fix patched for this...if not I guess I could go fix it myself in the source.

Comment: A partial solution can be found [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/04/02/a-solution-for-android-bluetooth-crashes.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug in the Android bluetooth code which does not appear to have a resolution at present.  Since other people keep finding this as well, I'm going to post what I found when tracing the problem through the bluetooth stack, even though it cannot really be applied as a resolution unless one is prepared to make major changes to an AOSP-based install.

Fundamentally, the problem is a SIGSEGV in btif_config.c at find_add_node() when alloc_node() fails after hearing too many unique BTLE hardware addresses.

Informative part of stack trace

```
D/BtGatt.btif(22509): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 4096
D/BtGatt.btif(22509): btif_gattc_add_remote_bdaddr device added idx=1
D/BtGatt.btif(22509): btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=beacon len=6 dev_type=2
F/libc    (22509): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22530 (BTIF)
I/DEBUG   (  171): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  171): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  171): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  171): pid: 22509, tid: 22530, name: BTIF  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
I/DEBUG   (  171): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  171):     r0 ffffffff  r1 00007d00  r2 00007c60  r3 74c7cf00
I/DEBUG   (  171):     r4 74c7cf10  r5 00000000  r6 756f95a8  r7 7503c671

I/DEBUG   (  171): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  171):     #00  pc 0004e68c  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so
I/DEBUG   (  171):     #01  pc 0004ea65  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (btif_config_set+156)
```

Disassembling, the code in question is this rather obviously problematic series of clearing r5 and then attempting to de-reference it as a base pointer:

```
       4e68a:   2500        movs    r5, #0
       4e68c:   6829        ldr r1, [r5, #0]
       4e68e:   b919        cbnz    r1, 4e698 <btif_gattc_test_command_impl+0x74c>
       4e690:   4630        mov r0, r6
       4e692:   f7dd ef78   blx 2c584 <strdup@plt>
```

This corresponds to the “if(!node->name)” check at the end of find_add_node()

```
static cfg_node* find_add_node(cfg_node* p, const char* name)
{
    int i = -1;
    cfg_node* node = NULL;
    if((i = find_inode(p, name)) < 0)
    {
        if(!(node = find_free_node(p)))
        {
            int old_size = alloc_node(p, CFG_GROW_SIZE);
            if(old_size >= 0)
            {
                i = GET_NODE_COUNT(old_size);
                node = &p->child[i];
                ADD_CHILD_COUNT(p, 1);
            } /* else clause to handle failure of alloc_node() is missing here */
        } else ADD_CHILD_COUNT(p, 1);
    }
    else node = &p->child[i];
    if(!node->name)   /* this will SIGSEGV if node is still NULL */
        node->name = strdup(name);
    return node;
}
```

Specifically, there is no else clause to handle the failure of alloc_node(), so when that happens (presumably due to running out of storage after hearing too many device addresses) the code falls through and attempts to dereference the name member of the node pointer without ever having set it to a non-null address.

**A fix would presumably need to involve:**

1. non-crash handling of this error case when a new record cannot be allocated
2. more aggressive discarding of past-heard addresses when new ones keep being heard and the number of records being stored becomes unreasonable

Comment: Is there an Android issue open for this?  Would be good to have a link to it is so.

Comment: Awesome find, Chris. I have been beating my head against the wall for a week on this, spending hours with a TI Bluetooth sniffer to try and find the cause.

Comment: As my app is currently doing proposed fix 2. hope that will save me from this situation at least for now.

Comment: I don't believe said discarding can be accomplished by an app - rather it is Android which fails and Android which needs to be patched.

Comment: @Chris, you are right, my app is 'discarding' found beacons in some case, but that wouldn't help avoid this situation. My misunderstanding.

Comment: @davidyoung - it should be noted that this has nothing to do with malformed packets. Rather, the stack will continue to accept data from hardware addresses it has already heard, but after too many will crash anytime it hears a new one for which it fails to allocate a record. When a phone gets in this state, you can power on a familiar beacon and it works fine, but power on a twin with a previously unheard hardware address and it will crash.

Comment: I have found a way to clear out these addresses.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/04/02/a-solution-for-android-bluetooth-crashes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Someone just opened an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67272 . Any supporting evidence should go there and hopefully Google fixes this in next release.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rare cause, but I had this issue when trying to use an L Tone with my Galaxy Nexus.  I tried various solutions, but nothing worked, then I remembered that I installed an app (in my rooted phone) that enabled Bluetooth LE (Normally 4.3 on Galaxy Nexus doesn't have access). Once I uninstalled the files the app installed, it seems to be working fine.

So, if thing aren't working still.. ask yourself if you've done anything custom on the phone that might be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Fix that worked for my S4 (i9500) :
After installing a custom ROM for Android 5.1.1, I started facing this 'Bluetooth stopped' issue. Since my phone was rooted, I installed 'Root Uninstaller' app and FROZE bluetooth services. I haven't had any issues after that. But again I am not sure if my bluetooth is working properly. It's just that I dont get those annoying pop-ups anymore.
Hope this helps someone !